# How to make a div skew in the reverse direction?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

I want to make a div like this

[image]

it is actually a part of design of a menu bar. The original menu bar is

[image]

I have tried My div but it looks like

[image]

My code is:

```
<div style="width: 75px; height: 200px; background:#32859d; transform:skewY(40deg); ">
</div>
```

Now what to do?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative angle for `skewY()` and set the `transform-origin` as `right top`.

```css
.skewed{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background: teal;
  transform-origin: right top;
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='skewed'></div>
```